# Point at infinity of the scheme $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

Let $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ be the scheme defined as either $\text{Proj }k[t]$ or obtained by gluing two affine lines appropriately. What is the point at infinity which in topology usually is given by $[0:1]$?

How about for $\mathbb{P}^1_S$, S not necessarily affine?

Comment: First off, $\mathbb{P}^1=Proj k[x,y]$. This might help a little- what else have you tried on this question? Do you know what the definition of $\mathbb{P}^1_S$ is?

Comment: I know that $\mathbb{P}^1_S = \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z} \times_\mathbb{Z} S$. I haven't really tried anything since I'm not sure how one proves that a candidate is the "point at infinity".

Comment: One way to think of the "point at infinity" is as the extra point you add to $\mathbb{A}^1$ to get $\mathbb{P}^1$. So a good way to attack this problem could be seeing how $\mathbb{A}^1$ lives inside each of these constructions and noticing which point you miss.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! We are gluing two affine lines $X, Y$ along $X - \{0\}$ and $Y - \{0\}$. We can embed $\mathbb{A}^1$ in two ways, either as $X$ or as $Y$. In the first case we will be missing $0 \in Y$ and in the second case $0 \in X$. Does it matter which $0$ is defined as the point at infinity? If we pick one as $[0:1]$, would the other one just correspond to $[1:0]$?